# insert data with mysqli in database table not working?connection works perfectly

Tags: php, mysqli

- It should say new record and then I should be able to see new data in items table
- connection to database file contains:

  ```
      $server="localhost";
      $login="root";
      $pass="";
      $database="floweritem";

      $con=mysqli_connect($server,$login,$pass,$database);
      if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "Failed connect to MYSQL".mysqli_connect_error();
      }
  ```
- form action
- PHP

  ```
      <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $Name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Name']);
      $Desc=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Desc']);
      $Size=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Size']);
      $Price=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Price']);


      //no problwm with connection to table or database
      $sql="INSERT INTO `items`(`Name`,`Description`,`Size`,`Price`) 
      VALUES($Name,$Desc,$Size,$Price)";
      echo $Desc;


      if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){ 
      echo "new record";
      }
      //always get wrong
      //can't find problem
      else{echo"Wrong";}
      mysqli_close($con);
      }
      ?>
  ```
- shows $Desc But Not successful to insert data in items table

Comment: use echo mysql_error();, it will print what happing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add single quotes against values.

Corrected Code:

```
 //no problwm with connection to table or database
    $sql="INSERT INTO `items`(`Name`,`Description`,`Size`,`Price`) 
    VALUES('$Name','$Desc','$Size','$Price')";
    echo $Desc;
```

Otherwise, MySQL will consider user entered values as MySQL keywords, hence creating Syntax errors.

Comment: what a stupid mistake Thanx anyway @Programming Student

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3):

New php code should be like this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $Name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Name']);
    $Desc=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Desc']);
    $Size=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Size']);
    $Price=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Price']);


    //no problwm with connection to table or database
    $sql="INSERT INTO `items`(`Name`,`Description`,`Size`,`Price`) 
    VALUES('$Name','$Desc','$Size','$Price')";
    echo $Desc;


    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){ 
    echo "new record";
    }
    //always get wrong
    //can't find problem
    else{echo"Wrong";}
    mysqli_close($con);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: kep one thing in mind by doing programming. if you are facing some problem with SQL query then you should use `var_dump()` function to see whether that query runs by programming or not. `var_dump()` will give true of false value. you can search more about `var_dump()` in google

Answer (score 1):

Try this its working :

**PHP :**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $Name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Name']);
    $Desc=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Desc']);
    $Size=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Size']);
    $Price=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Price']);


    //no problwm with connection to table or database
    $sql="INSERT INTO `items`(`Name`,`Description`,`Size`,`Price`) 
    VALUES('$Name','$Desc','$Size','$Price')";
    echo $Desc;


    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){ 
    echo "new record";
    }
    //always get wrong
    //can't find problem
    else{echo"Wrong";}
    mysqli_close($con);
    }
    ?>
```